# jQuery - Why does it alert unwanted things?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please see the code in jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gr7pa2yz/

```
var obj = {
x: 4,
y: 2,
z: {
    z1: {
        z11: "who",
        z12: 44
    }
},
zx: [3, 4, "string"],
zy: undefined
}

iterate(obj);

function iterate(obj) {
$.each(obj, function (i, e) {
    if (typeof e == "object") iterate(e);
    alert(e);
});
}
```

My question - You would see that the above code is alerting 3 things which am not able to understand how. It alerts - [Object object] twice and 3,4,string. how come?

Comment: Modern browsers (Chrome for example) come with Javascript debugger that lets you execute code step by step. At every step you can inspect variables values. Try using it.

Comment: I suggest using `console.log` for debugging things in general.

Comment: @Dimitri I strongly suggest **against** using `console.log`. It is much limited in abilities than full debug.

Comment: @Andrey My point was using console.log being a better option than using alert. Although I do agree that there are other, more complete alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

The two objects are

- `{ z11: "who", z12: 44 }`
- `{ z1: { z11: "who", z12: 44 } }`

You see `"[object Object]"` because `alert` calls object's `toString` method:

```
Object.prototype.toString(); // "[object Object]"
```

You also get `"3,4,string"` because of the array `[3, 4, "string"]`.

Arrays are objects too, but `Object.prototype.toString` is overriden by `Array.prototype.toString`, which calls `join`:

```
[3, 4, "string"].join(); // "3,4,string"
```

Answer (score 2):

You are iterating over the object and calling `alert` for every property of the object. Therefore, you are also alerting the objects `z` and `z1` themselves (not their content), which results in `[Object object]`.

Did you want something like this?

```
$.each(obj, function(i, e) {
  if (typeof e == 'object') {
    iterate(e);
  } else {
    alert(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's showing you `[object Object]` because, when faced with an object, your code first does this:

```
if (typeof e == "object") iterate(e);
```

...but then having done that, it does this:

```
alert(e);
```

That latter bit is what's giving you the `[object Object]` alert.

If your goal was to call `iterate` *instead of* calling `alert`:

```
if (typeof e == "object") iterate(e);
else alert(e);
```

or, this more easily debugged version:

```
if (typeof e == "object") {
    iterate(e);
}
else {
    alert(e);
}
```

---

Side note: `typeof null` is `"object"`; right now, `null`s will blow up your iterate function.